# Mapbox map with no style, only self hosted vector data

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to build a data visualization website and I didn't find how to build the map object without any style (or an "empty-like style") so only my vector data can be seen (a GeoJSON of some administrative areas **limited** to a particular country and some markers and popups with simple descriptions).

I am looking for something like image below, but without the world map. Just the upper layers (the blue ones).

[image: Example]

Comment: Hi and welcome on GIS.se,  don't really get what you want to remove from your map. Can you add some images to your question on what is on the mapbox map and you want to remove ? widgets, basemap, etc...

Comment: You should be aware if you use your own tiles, you should always use a mapbox token as billing is based on map load (same price if it's mapbox tiles or 3rd party) See https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/10162 Depending on your case, you may switch to maplibre.js https://github.com/MapLibre/maplibre-gl-js (a forked version of latest mapbox 1.x series, before license changes)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To remove the basemap from the example shown in your question
(https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/hover-styles/), just replace

```
style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11'
```

with

```
style: {version: 8,sources: {},layers: []}
```

which is an "empty" style without sources and layers.

Here's a demonstration:
https://jsbin.com/fowoluyawo/1/edit?html,output